# looking up sentence is positive or negative on the basis of emoticons c#

Tags: c#, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

I am doing project in c# and I am looking for the code which can help me to check either sentence is positive or negative or vague on the basis of emoticons.

For Example:

1. I love my country :) - (Positive) because it contain happy smiley
2. I love my country :( - (negative) because it contain sad smiley
3. weather is good :( :) -(vague) because it contain two smileys so it is vague to tell either it is positive or negative.
4. I don't want to go to College :( :) :) - (positive)because it contain two happy smileys and one sad.

My area of project is sentiment analysis.

Comment: python and java have libraries. you may need to write your own, see this q for ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199441/best-algorithmic-approach-to-sentiment-analysis

Comment: This isn't a real programming question, you're just asking how to do something as opposed to how to resolve an issue etc; have you tried solving this yourself? Have you even looked at any search results for "how to search a string"?

Comment: You could count the ')' and the '(' in order to estimate the positive factor.

Answer (score 2):

Another regex ;)

```
string input = "I don't want to go to College :( :) :) ";

var score = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<a>:\))|(?<b>:\()")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Groups["a"].Success ? 1 : -1)
                 .Sum();
```

Comment: I like it. +1 for not using side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx)

```
var upScore = Regex.Matches(input, @":\)").Count;
var downScore = Regex.Matches(input, @":\(").Count;
var totalScore = upScore - downScore;
```

Although it's *bad practice* to use side effects in a `MatchEvaluator`, you could also use `Regex.Replace` to make a single pass through the string:

```
var score = 0;
MatchEvaluator match = m =>
{
    score += m.Value[1] == ')' ? 1 : -1;
    return m.Value;
};
Regex.Replace(input, ":[()]", match);
```

Comment: It could work if **a)** regex pattern **b)** order of parameters were correct.

Comment: But it still has some bugs. guess where?

Comment: @I4V got it. thanks for keeping me honest