# feature extraction from the product review

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for some NLP algorithm to get the product features from the product review.

For Example:

I have some reviews on a laptop and i want to extract the features people discussed in their reviews.

Please Help..

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You should really read some paper on sentiment analysis, try to implement approach and then come back with specific example and questions. In current wording you will get nothing but general statements that you can read on Wikipedia anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to go about this would be extracting the key words themselves that you find in the review text. The words that denote a positive sentiment can be given a positive rating and the words that denote a negative sentiment a negative one. You can also introduce scaling for them based on the extent of the sentiment each words might denote, like the word 'excellent' should have a higher sentiment rating than that of the word 'good'. The final rated review value can be the aggregate of the detected ratings. You can also refer this, seems related:

[Best Algorithmic Approach to Sentiment Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199441/best-algorithmic-approach-to-sentiment-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

This book:
  [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B009KET3PU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009KET3PU)  (Sentiment Analysis and Opinion Mining by Bing Liu)

The most common example, used in most chapters, is that of understanding camera reviews. Once you've read that book you either know how to do what you want, or have a reading list of papers to study next, or you have a more specific question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a combination of both rules and some learning classification method. Since you can define the domain clearly - only some words will ever be used to define features of a laptop.

Rule based approaches in my experience tend to prefer recall over precision, and a supervised learning classifier might even that out. http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/
And Regex can be very useful too. http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I hope this provides a good starting point.