# Sentiment analysis from scratch

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I want to create a sentiment analysis tool from scratch. It doesn't have to be highly complicated. I want to understand the techniques (even if they are quite basic and don't include the latest and the greatest) and be able to code them without using libraries. Can anyone, please, point me the right sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Algorithmic Approach to Sentiment Analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199441/best-algorithmic-approach-to-sentiment-analysis)

Comment: I suggested that as a duplicate, not because the question is the same, but because the answers there are basically what you would be told here. (I'd personally recommend Bing Lui's 2012 book... though I notice he has a book, published June 2015, which is twice the size, so maybe that is better choice.) https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/