# Sources of classified sentiment data?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, training-data

I'm looking to train a naive Bayes with some new data sources that haven't been used before. I've already looked at the Lee & Pang corpus of IMDB reviews and the MPQA opinion corpus. I'm looking for new web services that fit the following criteria.

1. Easily Classified - must have a like/dislike or 5 star rating
2. Readily available
3. Pertain to new material (less important than the first two)

Here are some samples I have come up with on my own.

- Etsy API
- Rotten Tomatoes API
- Yelp API

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Training data for sentiment analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551262/training-data-for-sentiment-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

In Pang&Lee's later work (2008) "Opinion Mining and Sentiment Analysis" [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/omsa/omsa.pdf) they have a section for publicly available resources. It has links to those corpora.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sentiment140](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students). It has a corpus that you can download and train with. You can easily extend to new tweets.