# how to get dictionaries of positive and negative words for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, wordnet, sentiment-analysis

I am doing work on  sentiment analysis of tweets .can any one tell me is there any way to get available dictionary for research work that contain positive , negative and neutral words .
THANKS

Comment: You have the following prev. questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869310/sentiment-analysis-wordnet-sentiwordnet-lexicon
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188706/sentiment-analysis-dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

Use SentiWordnet. SentiWordNet is a lexical resource for opinion mining. SentiWordNet assigns to each synset of WordNet three sentiment scores: positivity, negativity, objectivity.

http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/